# Windows.h macros not defined

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm making a simple GUI library, and I've gotten to the first test. The weird thing is, none of the windows macros seem to be defined. I'm getting errors like "'NULL' was not declared in scope" and "'HANDLE' was not declared in scope." I'm thinking it might be the way I organized the code because the stuff in the entry file easywin.hpp isn't defined either, but it SEEMS like it should work. Here's (most) of easywin.hpp:

```
#ifndef EASYWIN_BASE_HPP
#define EASYWIN_BASE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <map>

//Strings are used everywhere, so might as well use them globally
using std::string;

/**
 * A namespace to encapsulate WinAPI and prevent name clashing.
**/

namespace WinAPI{
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <commctrl.h>
}

//header includes (ordered according to inheritance)
#include "Application.hpp"
#include "Object.hpp"
    #include "Widget.hpp"
        #include "Container.hpp"
            #include "Window.hpp"
                #include "Dialog.hpp"
                    //not implemented yet, so don't include
                    //#include "Light.hpp"
                    #include "Heavy.hpp"
            // there are more container types
        #include "Control.hpp"
            #include "Textbox.hpp"
        #include "Tooltip.hpp"

//source includes
//needed to simplify class dependencies
#include "Application.cpp"
#include "Object.cpp"
    #include "Widget.cpp"
        #include "Container.cpp"
            #include "Window.cpp"
                #include "Dialog.cpp"
                    //not implemented yet, so don't include
                    //#include "Light.cpp"
                    #include "Heavy.cpp"
            // there are more container types
        #include "Control.cpp"
            #include "Textbox.cpp"
        #include "Tooltip.cpp"

#endif
```

I just don't get it. If I'm including everything in this file, those files SHOULD get what's defined in this file. What did I do wrong?

EDIT: To encourage better answers, I'll post the git repository:

https://github.com/PiMaster/Easywin

Comment: Neither of the two answers below have answered my question. I see no reason whatsoever that would cause this. All of the files are included in the file that includes/defines the things that are never included/defined, after they are included/defined. Does ANYONE know why this isn't working!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment on IronMensan's answer because it's entirely correct but I can't fit in there...

The windows's API has functions that take parameters of type "HANDLE" in the global namespace, in other words "::HANDLE". The windows libraries are **already** compiled to do this and the compiled code exists in such libraries as user32.lib/dll.

The purpose of windows.h is to define the types and functions that *already* exist in the library so you can call them. What you have done is define some *unrelated* types for example WinAPI::HANDLE which is fine, but in no way alters the fact that library contains functions which need a ::HANDLE as a parameter.

I understand what you are trying to do, and it's a good aim. However there is no way that it can possibly work.

Comment: While this may be helpful, it still doesn't answer my immediate problem. For some reason, nothing in the include file is registered as being defined in any of the other files, even though they are defined/included before those files are included.

Comment: Where do you think you've defined "HANDLE" for example?

Comment: HANDLE should be defined in windows.h. My compiler says that it isn't defined, even if I take windows.h out of WinAPI. I think I have an idea, though. The compiler seems to be compiling my .cpp files before any other file - should I put my function definitions in other .hpp files?

Comment: It turns out this was correct - my compiler was compiling the .cpp files first. After renaming everything to be .hpp files, I just had to fix the normal compiler errors and the weird logic error I'm fixing now >.> Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the WinAPI namespace.  Even if you manage to get everything to compile by scoping things that need it with WinAPI::, the linker won't be able to find anything and it still won't build.

To avoid name conflicts, you should put all of your code in a separate namespace and leave Windows.h alone.

Comment: I like the idea of keeping WinAPI in a namespace - it's kind of like putting it in a box. Also, I may want to extend my library to include socket programming, and window's decided to use names that I would like to use in their winsock.h file. I see no reason to think the linker won't be able to find anything because I've tested enclosing windows.h in a namespace before in a much simpler project, and it worked.

So, this answer is **completely useless** to me, as you didn't answer my question or even say anything relevant to the topic at hand.

Comment: @PiMaster `typedef void *HANDLE` is part of windows.h; it's not a preprocessor symbol.  So if you put windows.h in `namespace WinAPI`, it becomes `WinAPI::HANDLE`.  Thus my comment about "scoping things that need it with WinAPI::" answers your question.

Comment: @PiMaster - You may like the idea of keeping windows.h in a box, but you seem to be under the mistaken impression that it's a header file built in the last 10 years and designed to accommodate c++.  You couldn't be more wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when things like that happen to me, it's because of a double definition of the protection macro. This usually happens when you copy and paste a header file and forget to change the protection macro. Try search for `EASYWIN_BASE_HPP` in other files. On newer compilers, you can also use `#pragma once` to make it simpler.

Also, it's generally not a good idea to use `using` in a header file. Users of the header file may use more than one header file from different libraries. One of these may have a conflict with the `string` identifier.

Comment: A search shows that easywin.hpp is the only file with definitions for EASYWIN_BASE_HPP. I've moved the using std::string to easywin. Any other ideas?